# .order() by attributes with 2 conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Every answer has a `:votes_count` attribute and is ordered by it.

Additionally every answer has `:accept_toggle` attribute.

**Current code:**

```
<div class="">
  <%= render @question.answers.order(:votes_count).reverse %>
</div>
```

How can i still order answers by `:votes_count` but as soon an answer has an `:accept_toggle` it is raised to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, deleting reverse, this would sort answers first by accept_toggle and then by votes count:

```
<%= render @question.answers.order(accept_toggle: :desc, votes_count: :desc)%>
```

If  you want to sort them first by number of votes and then by accept_toggle try:

```
<%= render @question.answers.order(votes_count: :desc, accept_toggle: :desc)%>
```

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order).

Comment: This is giving me an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Comment: `order` does not accept a hash...try this `order("votes_count desc, accept_toggle desc")`